# Mission to Mars: halachic challenges

Tags: halacha, technology, travel, science, outer-space

There is talk in the scientific community of a manned Mars mission: sending an elderly couple to slingshot past Mars and return to Earth as a trial mission, toward eventual other missions that will land there in the future. The mission would last around 300 days.

What would be the halachic challenges that the couple could face on a day-to-day basis? (This question doesn't ask whether space exploration/travel is halachically desirable.)

Comment: I assume you mean challenges that are unique to space travel (meaning kosher food is not the answer you are looking for).

Comment: Good thing they are elderly or Mikva would be a big problem.

Comment: @DoubleAA see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26921/can-i-make-a-mikvah-using-artificial-rain

Comment: Perhaps kosher food would be a problem. Space food often consists of powdered food that needs hydration. It may not be possible, for health reasons, to provide a balanced diet using novel space food storage techniques. I don't know!

Comment: I know there are disagreements over how often you would need to pray in space. This could cause problems, especially since you would be required to keep to an exercise regime when on board. Chagim?

Comment: Davening,sefirah,sukkos,kiddush levanah...

Comment: @sam wow kiddush levanah is a interesting point

Comment: Rav Menashe Klein has a tshuvah on saying kiddush kevanah on the moon. [Mishneh Halachos 6:259](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1878&pgnum=316)

Comment: But does one say כשם שאני רוקד...

Comment: What about a minyan for kaddish?

Comment: Why kaddish and not minyan?

Comment: @Shmuel Who cares? Where would you keep the water that is Karka?

Comment: @DoubleAA true, they're not landing

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9250/when-does-somebody-living-in-space-e-g-iss-observe-shabbat

Comment: you couldnt really wash your hands using a kli. what would be the beracha on placing your hands in a ball of 'floating' water when in orbit in space...

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Jumping off what bondonk said, maybe a ball of water floating in space is considered Ashboren regarding Mikva. After all it isn't in a kli and it isn't flowing anywhere.

Comment: @DoubleAA That's only if water can be made de-Sheuvinized (the question there). If not, it won't help. On the other hand, if you have lots of airspace in the spacecraft (and natural air there), one can condense the water evaporated there into a blob of water that won't be sheuvim. That creates other interesting questions.

Comment: P'ru urvu, hearing shofar, eating in a sukkah. Candles

Comment: Burning chometz, burning your fingernails, kaparos. On the other hand -- http://www.decanter.com/wine-news/opinion/the-editors-blog/space-wine-possible-far-far-away-371816/

Comment: Voting to close as too broad, as per the extensive list cited [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3744/).

Answer (score 3):

This answer will focus just on those aspects which are unique to a Mars Mission, as those relating to any long-distance visit to a foreign locale have been dealt with elsewhere.

### Travel in Space

- [When does somebody living in space (e.g. ISS) observe Shabbat?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9250/when-does-somebody-living-in-space-e-g-iss-observe-shabbat)

### Life on Mars

*These questions can be summarized as follows: For those Halakhot which depend on astronomical \ planetary variables, do we follow  Earth or local (Martian) values?*

- *Calendar*.  A day on Mars is about 40 minutes longer than an Earth day.  Does one go based on the the Mars day or the Earth day?

  - If we do go by the Martian day, then Mars will fall behind at a rate of about 1 day per (Earth) month.  The Martian calendar will need to be re-calculated (subtract one day per month, etc) to stay in sync with the Earth calendar.
- *Kiddush Levana.*  Mars has two moons, Phobos and Deimos.  When would one say Kiddush Levana?  Would one say it once per orbit for each of these moons, once per Martian "month" (which would probably be divorced from the lunar cycles), or follow the Earth tradition?  Perhaps one wouldn't say Kiddush Levana at all.
- *Zmanim*.  Seems pretty straight-forward, as Halakhic time is based on location and length of daylight anyways.

Comment: Wikified.  Feel free to add.

Comment: I don't see why living on Mars you would go by the Martian moons for kiddish levana

Comment: כל מצוה שהיא תלויה בארץ
אינה נוהגת אלא בארץ;
ושאינה תלויה בארץ
נוהגת בין בארץ בין בחוצה לארץ
Kiddushin 27, Mishna

Comment: @bondonk Because you can see their phases?

Comment: @Shmuel haaretz is the land of israel not earth per se

Comment: @bondonk - I'm aware of that, but it doesn't take too much creativity to extend that principle to other planets.

Comment: @Shmuel with creativity you could say that 'lo bashamayim he' means mitzvot don't apply on mars! Its difficult to deviate from the traditional understanding on the moon being ours but it could be.