# Should a person observe Rosh Hodesh & say "Kiddush Ha'Aretz" if he lives permanently on the moon?

Tags: halacha, rosh-chodesh-new-month, kiddush-levanah, moon

This is not meant to be a "Purim Torah" question.

The concept of Rosh Hodesh is based on the orbit of the moon around Earth. But, with the proposal of sending people to live permanently on Mars, I assume that it won't be long before they have people live permanently on the moon.

So, if someone did live permanently on the moon. Things are relative. From that person's viewpoint, Earth looks like the moon's "moon". So, it would like Earth has a "molad". Would you have to observe Rosh Hodesh at the same time and in the same manner as if you would living on Earth?

Similarly, I guess you would call it "Kiddush Ha'Aretz" (or "Adamah?") - would you have to recite that each month?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9250/759

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30683/759

Comment: you may be interested in reading http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=10217

Comment: @DoubleAA, I don't think we ought to dupe a question raising a particular concern with a question asking what concerns there may be in a related situation.

Comment: "the proposal of sending people to live permanently on Mars": many people have proposed that for me over the years. I guess you've gotten it, too, huh?

Comment: @mevaqesh Thanks for the reminder. I'd like to be fair, so, B"N, I will try to read your linked material in the next few days, prior to commenting on it, if I need to. Shabbat Shalom.

Comment: Shabbat Shalom to you as well.

Answer (score 3):

One consideration raised by R. M. Kasher is whether one s obligated in commandments on the moon or in outer space at all given the Torah expression  “all the days which you are alive on this earth” (Deut. 12:1) in the context of mitzvos. Apparently he concluded that one is obligated see [here](http://www.oztorah.com/2008/03/torah-in-space-ask-the-rabbi/) (which cites this from JD Bleich, “Contemporary Halachic Problems”, vol.1.) and [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CD8QFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.yutorah.org%2F2008%2F1053%2F724883.pdf&ei=8QTmVPmCDYm5ggTVnoLYAw&usg=AFQjCNHWtU30-yUMrtsIlMNXEDRHm5mziQ) (which cites this from the 5730 issue of No'am)

Rabbi Benzion Firrer, however does hold that one is exempt from all commandments while in space (cited there and [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CD8QFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.yutorah.org%2F2008%2F1053%2F724883.pdf&ei=8QTmVPmCDYm5ggTVnoLYAw&usg=AFQjCNHWtU30-yUMrtsIlMNXEDRHm5mziQ) citing the 5730 issue of No'am).

In regards to kiddush Levana in particular Rav Kasher writes that one loses performing the mitzvah of Kiddush Levana on the moon. quoted [here](http://www.ravaviner.com/2009/11/man-on-moon.html) from "Man on the Moon" by Ha-Rav Menachem Kasher (pp. 51-55). This is also the view of R. M. Schneerson quoted [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CD8QFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.yutorah.org%2F2008%2F1053%2F724883.pdf&ei=8QTmVPmCDYm5ggTVnoLYAw&usg=AFQjCNHWtU30-yUMrtsIlMNXEDRHm5mziQ) (citing Rozen, Yitzchak Yehuda, 1999, "The Torah in The Space Age" Proceedings of the Associations of Orthodox Jewish Scientists, 2:175-179)

In regards to time bound mitzvos in general Rabbi Menahem Kasher ruled that “The situation on the moon [or Mars] is equivalent to the north and south poles; therefore posit a 24-hour day, with alternating periods of 12 hours day and 12 hours night regardless of the presence or absence of light from the sun”. quoted [here](http://www.oztorah.com/2008/03/torah-in-space-ask-the-rabbi/).

Comment: I'm not downvoting, because you are only citing a second hand source, but p51-55 are just his discussion of keeping Mitzvot/Shabbat in general. I don't see any reference to Kiddush Levana there.

Comment: @DoubleAA If you find the correct pages then please edit it in.

Comment: Thanks. You also addressed the general question about living on other planets, though many of them have their own moons. I may raise this as another question, actually.