# Kiddush Levanah in Outer Space

Tags: kiddush-levanah, outer-space

Inspired by [questions about observing Shabbos in outer space](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9250/when-does-somebody-living-in-space-e-g-iss-observe-shabbat), I've been wondering about Kiddush Levanah. Would someone living in space use similar opinions to determine when to sanctify the moon as someone seeking to determine when to observe Shabbos? I'm particularly curious about how someone living on the moon, itself would do Kiddush Levanah.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should a person observe Rosh Hodesh & say "Kiddush Ha'Aretz" if he lives permanently on the moon?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55267/should-a-person-observe-rosh-hodesh-say-kiddush-haaretz-if-he-lives-permane)

Comment: @DanF That is certainly an interesting question, but it is somewhat different from what I'm asking. I'm asking specifically about preforming Kiddush Levanah, itself and not inquiring about an alternative "Kiddush Ha'Aretz". I do, however see how these questions are closely related and that answers will likely rely on some of the same sources.

Comment: More likely a dupe of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/65874/759 Note Kiddush Levana has nothing to do with times like Shabbat. It's a blessing said on seeing an waxing moon.

Comment: @DoubleAA That's also a great question, but once again, not exactly what I'm asking here. That question pertains to saying Kiddush Levana for moons of other planets. I'm still talking about our moon in this question.

Comment: @DoubleAA I also understand that Kiddush Levanah is unrelated to Shabbos. The connection I'm making is based on the fact that one never observes a waxing moon in space (or on the moon), just as one cannot observe a halachic sunset (to mark zmanim) in space. As one may rely on one's point of departure from the Earth to determine zmanim, I was wondering if one may use one's point of departure as a reference to determine when the moon is observed as waxing.

Comment: @Ze'ev I don't know what that means "to determine when the moon is observed as waxing". Would you also say a blessing on lightning if there is a storm in the town you departed from?

Comment: @Ze'ev Note that Rosh Chodesh is based on the time of the molad in Yerushalaim, not your local time even though the ceremony of kiddush levana is done when you see it in your current location. It would appear that not seeing the moon would be like the case when it is obscured (such as because of a storm) in your local placfe.

Comment: @sabbahillel Or if you spent all 15 days of waxing moon in a plane flying west to stay in daylight. Or if you are in Antarctica.

Comment: Outer space is very big. Where in outer space are you talking about? The ISS is basically just really high off the ground (and moving so fast as to cross the dateline very often) but effectively sees the same moon as we do. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Maybe he could say Kiddush Levanah on RC since, you know, he could see the moon 24/7...