# How does one create a mikvah in a region without precipitation?

Tags: mikvah-ritual-bath

How does one create a mikvah in a desert?
(IOW, it never rains or snow here).

This is not quite theoretical - IIUC, it *is* a real problem in, say, some parts of Egypt.

PS. The source of drinking water can be a long [aqueduct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aqueduct_(water_supply)) or a deep well...

Comment: If you're referring to a place with no natural water source and which would have been entirely uninhabitable until recently, why would you expect that there is a way to build a Mikva there?

Comment: @DoubleAA: how about a well?

Comment: If there's a well they can just dip in the well

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26921/can-i-make-a-mikvah-using-artificial-rain

Comment: Expanding your abbreviations will make your question simpler to read. It's generally good to avoid them aside from comments where you're running out of characters.

Comment: Hmmm ... how about a geyser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Ohr.edu](https://ohr.edu/ask_db/ask_main.php/95/Q1/) says that in an area where there is no rain, snow can be trucked in.

> Putting snow in a mikveh and letting it melt is in fact one of the
>   methods sometimes used to fill a mikveh. I hear that during dry spells
>   in Arizona they sometimes truck in snow from the Sierra Mountains to
>   fill mikvehs.

See also [Chevel Nachloso 6:25](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%91%D7%9C_%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%95_%D7%95_%D7%9B%D7%94)

Comment: Thanks! Would a slab of ice do? Does snow have to be natural?

Comment: @sds http://www.tabletmag.com/jewish-life-and-religion/119907/msh210

Comment: Ah, so we can just freeze the tap water and place it into the mikvah to melt. Thanks!

Comment: a natural underground or mountain stream /spring would work. But the ice story is way cooler :)

Comment: Would this be kosher for a women's mikvah? That's really interesting.

Comment: @sds tap water would be "she'uvim" already, invalidating it for a mikva, so that wouldn't work. However, taking ice blocks from a frozen river or the like would be a good idea

Comment: @ezra Why would any mikveh differ from another in what allows it to be metaher? If it's kosher, it's kosher.

Comment: @DonielF - Since men do not have to dip in by halacha, even a swimming pool is kosher for a men's mikvah. But since women are required to dip in by halacha, the are naturally _many more_ halachos for them.

Comment: @ezra The article discussed Keilim. The passuk explicitly compares a mikveh for Keilim to a mikveh for a woman (see AZ 75b).

Comment: Good reference on the topic [here](https://www.kollelmenachem.org/media/pdf/433/juNS4330495.pdf) page 40