# How is a mikve filled in for the first time?

Tags: mikvah-ritual-bath, water

I am wondering how one fills a *mikve* for the first time?

Most of the works I consulted on the topic (e.g., the very good document [here](https://www.kollelmenachem.org/media/pdf/433/juNS4330495.pdf) or Artscroll Mishna Mikvaos) mention "forty *seah* of rainwater are gathered into a *bor*" but without details on how to accomplish this practically. Remember that for a kosher mikve, water has to flow naturally and cannot be drawn from containers.

I know it is possible to fill a mikve with ice (under very strict conditions) but assume that ice is not available everywhere, especially in summer months. And since I have seen opinions ranging from 575-1000 liters for forty *seah*, I assume waiting for rainfall to occur naturally during construction might take a long time, and not work at all for months in hot regions (e.g., Israel).

So what is practically being done?

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/83891/how-does-the-rainwater-enter-the-bor https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/83198/how-does-one-create-a-mikvah-in-a-region-without-precipitation

Comment: What's wrong with construction taking a few months? This isn't something you order on Amazon Prime

Comment: @DoubleAA I can see at least two things going wrong: (1) if you leave water stagnate over months, it will turn bad and (2) still after months you might not get the quantity you need. Anyway I am asking a fact-based question, either people know what is practiced or not. Maybe mikve constructors are waiting months but I would guess not. I am continuing to research this and will post back what I learn

Comment: They must have a way of keeping the water from going bad even after they build it.

Comment: @DoubleAA could be - chemicals (e.g., chlorine) could do this like in a pool - question is whether they remove the status of rainwater (e.g., if accumulation over the months is > 3 luggin). The other alternative appears to feed it from a spring

Comment: Digging springs for this is largely a modern idea, is more expensive, and doesn't work everywhere.

Comment: I remember passing by this mikveh in Bnei Brak, which seems to have big water tanks. So they must have a way to conserve the rainwater. https://goo.gl/maps/KsVAWR8TNLpsNvXn6

Answer (score 2):

One source of water would be an [artesian aquifer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artesian_aquifer).

(For an example of using artesian water for a mikveh see [here.](https://henryabramson.com/2019/11/10/descending-into-the-14th-century-mikvah-in-carpentras-france/)) 
Ideally the water would just flow into the mikveh.
If it's not possible, there are ways of bringing the water up from the artesian well without making it become "shauvin" "drawn" water which would be invalid.
I remember learning that this is done for mikvaos by using air pressure. (I'll try and source this last claim.)

It's also worth noting that there is a major machlokes regarding using artificial ice for a mikveh. It's a "hot topic" with major opinions on both sides, but there are halachically valid opinions who would allow for creating ice in a machine from tap water and using that for creating a mikveh.

When I learned mikvaos a number of rabbonim told me that we only rely on this b'shas dechak gadol, until some other kosher water could be obtained; but CYLOR.

See this [article](https://www.koltorah.org/halachah/creating-a-mikveh-with-snow-natural-and-artificial-ice-by-rabbi-chaim-jachter) for background info about using natural or artificial ice.

Comment: I see now that page 71 [here](https://www.kollelmenachem.org/media/pdf/433/juNS4330495.pdf) describes an air pressure system similar to what you describe